# AFNetworking: How can I get a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm trying to modify [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe) in order to donwload a json file from my web, but I'm stuck since is the first time I'm using AFNetworking.

My best attempt is the following:

```
@interface LOArticulos (){
    NSData *jsonResponse;
}

@end

@implementation LOArticulos

+(LOArticulos *)sharedInstance{
    static LOArticulos *_sharedArticles;

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        _sharedArticles = [[LOArticulos  alloc]init];
    });
    return _sharedArticles;
}

-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _todosLosArticulos = [self loadArticlesFromJSON];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)loadArticlesFromJSON{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/turkish/json/lakari.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                         {
                                             jsonResponse = JSON;
                                         }

                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request,NSHTTPURLResponse *response,NSError *error, id JSON)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error,error.userInfo);

                                         }];
     NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    [operation start];

    NSMutableArray *articlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:jsonArray.count];

    for (NSDictionary *articleDictionary in jsonArray) {
        LOArticulo *articulo = [[LOArticulo alloc]init];
        articulo.ID = articleDictionary[@"id"];
        articulo.marca = articleDictionary[@"marca"];
        articulo.modelo = articleDictionary[@"modelo"];
        articulo.price = articleDictionary[@"precio"];
        articulo.categoria = articleDictionary[@"categoria"];
        articulo.photoURL = articleDictionary[@"photoUrl"];
        [articlesArray addObject:articulo];
    }        
    return articlesArray;
}

@end
```

Unfortunately it does not work, and I got the following error:

"**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'**"

Please, could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `jsonResponse` is already serialized into an NSDictionary (or NSArray) upon entering the completion block, not NSData as you are expecting. To get around this, use a simple AFHTTPRequestOperation, and serialize the response object yourself using whatever options you wish, such as `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`.

Comment: I'm working on your solution. I NSLog exactly the same  as in original code if I do it inside the block, but the method is returning null. I'll edit my original post.